# Write schema to an existing ORC file

Tags: hive, orc

We are facing the following issue: we use hive 1.2.x to write orc files, it is a known problem, that hive before version 2.x does not write the orc column names into the orc file (it writes only col_0,col_1,etc.).
We would like to use an other application which reads the schema from the orc file and can not connect to hcat metastore for the correct column names. Unfortunately we do not have a chance to upgrade to 2.x version of hive.

Is there any solution to "append" or replace the correct column names into these exitsing orc files? Thanks in advnace for you help.

Comment: HDFS files are immutable by definition *(OK, now you can Append or Truncate an existing file, but there is no way to change some bytes at a specific position)* so I cannot imagine how you could rewrite the ORC footer **in place**. You would have to re-create the entire file -- for example with Spark.